# PHP: Extract video ID from YouTube URLs

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

Do I do something wrong?
I need the youtube code, but it doesn't return the real value.

```
if(preg_match_all("http:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/v\/(.*)(.*)", $row->n_texto, $matches){
    $code = $image_to_thumb .= "http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/".$matches[1][0]."/0.jpg";
}
```

**Edit - ircmaxell** Based on the comment, the link structure in the text is:

> http:// www.youtube.com/v/plMvAh10HVg%26hl=en%26fs=1%26rel=0

---

**Update**

The problem is: my code return a link like this:

```
http://www.youtube.com/v/plMvAh10HVg%26hl=en%26fs=1%26rel=0
```

Can I stop it with regexp before appear `%26hl=en%26fs=1%26rel=0`?

Comment: That link you provided is not a valid link.  Even if you urldecode it, it'll still be `plMvAh10HVg&hl=en&fs=1&rel=0` which isn't a valid URL (it should have a `?` prior to the first `&` bit)...

Comment: Can't youtube links be watch?v=blah as well?  If you're only looking at the /v/blah links, just use parse_url to get the path and drop the /v at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is not correct.  There are more than a few things wrong with it.  Now, as far as what you want, try this:

```
#http://(?:.*)youtube.com/v/([^/\#?]+)#
```

Now, as for why, let's look at the regex:

```
http://(?:.*)youtube.com
```

You're looking for a string that starts with `http://`, has anything after (`www.`, `ww2.`, or nothing).

```
/v/
```

You're looking for `/v/` as the start of the URL.

```
([^/\\#?]+)
```

You're looking for everything else UP TO another `/`, a query string (`?`) or a anchor (`#`).  So that should match the ID you're looking for.

So, it would be

```
if(preg_match("#http://(?:.*)youtube.com/v/([^/\#?]+)#", $row->n_texto, $matches){
    $code = $image_to_thumb .= "http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/".$matches[1]."/0.jpg";
}
```

If you wanted to find all:

```
if(preg_match_all("#http://(?:.*)youtube.com/v/([^/\#?]+)#", $row->n_texto, $matches){
    foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {
        $code = $image_to_thumb .= "http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/".$match."/0.jpg";
    }
}
```

Comment: Strenge, it return a message:

Comment: The problem is:
my code return a link like this: http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/plMvAh10HVg%26hl=en%26fs=1%26rel=0
Can I stop it with regexp before appear %26hl=en%26fs=1%26rel=0??

Comment: @user580463: show your input text, since [a test shows it works fine](http://lumadis.be/regex/test_regex.php?id=651) given example text...

Answer (score 0):

the link provided has a space before the 1st w in www.youtube.com, the code you need is :

```
if(preg_match_all("%http://www\.youtube\.com/v/([\w]+)%i", $row->n_texto , $matches)){
    $code = $image_to_thumb .= "http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/".$matches[1][0]."/0.jpg";
}
```

also, the url you have is encoded, you may want to use urldecode($row->n_texto) before using it.

Answer (score -1):

```
^http://\w{0,3}.?youtube+\.\w{2,3}/watch\?v=[\w-]{11}
```

according to http://www.regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=2569

Comment: That regex looks off.  Why would/should it match `youtubeee.com`?

Comment: If you're going to post a regex you didn't create, you should test it thoroughly first.  Most of the regexes you can find on the web are crap, and the ones on RegExLib are no exception.